# How to parse this array of dicts and extract key columns from a big query external table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this Gaint Array of (dicts) loaded from a Json in a date partitioned  big query external table with table structure as below as

| Field name | Type. | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| meta | Record | Nullable |
| Messages | String | Repeated |
| date | Integer | Nullable |

Every "Messages" Field is in its own row/record in my Bigquery table (New_line_delimited_Json)

I am trying to parse the "messages" field/column  to extract some fields Key1 and Key2 which happens to be inside an  Array (of dicts). For sake of simplicity ,below is the snippet of json of which "messages" is a field that I am trying to unnest/explode.

**Ignore this schema;updated schema below*****

```
 [
  {
    "meta": {
      "table": "FEED",
      "source": "CP1"
    },
    "Messages": [
      "{
      "Key1":"2022-01-10",
      "Key2":"H21257061"
      }"
       ],
    "date": "20220110"
  },
  {
    "meta": {
      "table": "FEED",
      "source": "CP1"
    },
    "Messages": [
      "{
      "Key1":"2022-01-11",
      "Key2":"H21257062"
      }"
       ],
    "date": "20220111"
  }
]
```

**updated schema on 01/17**

```
{
  "meta": {
    "table": "FEED",
    "source": "CP1"
  },
  "Messages": [
    "{
    "Key1":"2022-01-10",
    "Key2":"H21257061"
    }",
    "{
    "Key1":"2022-01-10",
    "Key2":"H21257062"
    }"
  ],
  "date": "20220110"
},
```

**updated schema representation on 01/17:**

[image]

so far I have tried this but I am getting sql output of key1 and Key2 as Nulls

```
    WITH table  AS (SELECT Messages as array_column FROM `project.dataset.table`  )
SELECT 
    json_extract_scalar(flattened_array, '$.Messages.key1') as key1,
    json_extract_scalar(flattened_array, '$.Messages.key2') as key2
FROM table t 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.array_column) AS flattened_array
```

Comment: I think you oversimplified your example of data and it schema - they don't even match each other. and code sample also is out of any sync with presented data. please revisit the question!

Comment: In additional to what Mikhail said, can you please provide a complete sample JSON file with an object? I tried recreating your scenario but the array you provided is not adequate for table creation.

Comment: @AnjelaB - Just updated the Json .My bad ,the file is too huge to edit and simplify

Comment: still - data sample for messages does not match the schema!! in schema it looks like repeated string, but in data sample it shown as a repeated record!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Also there are 20 other {K,V} pairs inside "Messages" below and above the keys(Key1,Key2) I mentioned .I edited the file heavily to make it simple

Comment: Other pairs and how many of them - does not matter at all. But without knowing your schema  - it is not possible to answer your question, unless someone will just try shooting in the air with guesses

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - What schema are you talking ? i provided everything I had . Am I missing anything ? I can share the whole json as an attachement if i have that option here?

Comment: whatever you call `table structure` - I called schema in my comments

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - I have modfied the schema and added {} inside messages .hopefully this should work

Answer (score 0):

Still a little ambiguous so I assume below correctly represents your table (at least it matches the structure/schema in your question)

[image]

If my assumption correct  - consider below approach

```
select * except(id) from (
  select to_json_string(t) id, kv[offset(0)] as key, kv[safe_offset(1)] as value
  from your_table t, 
  t.messages as message,
  unnest([struct( split(translate(message, '"', ''), ':') as kv)])
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('Key1', 'Key2'))
```

If / when applied to above sample data  - output is

[image]

**Edit**: Trying to help you further - Ok so, looks like your table looks like below

[image]

In this case - try below (quite light modification of previous version)

```
select * except(id) from (
  select to_json_string(t) id, kv[offset(0)] as key, kv[safe_offset(1)] as value
  from your_table t, 
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(messages, r'"[^"]+":"[^"]+"')) as message,
  unnest([struct( split(translate(message, '"', ''), ':') as kv)])
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('Key1', 'Key2'))
```

with output

[image]

But obviously, I would use below simplest approach

```
select 
  json_extract_scalar(messages, '$.Key1') as Key1,
  json_extract_scalar(messages, '$.Key2') as Key2
from your_table
```

Comment: I plugged in the query and its still giving me null values .Sorry for the back and forth .I think this is a fair assumption for table .

Comment: both these queries gave me the same error No matching signature for function REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(STRING, STRING)..                                           
                                                    No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signature: JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(STRING, [STRING]) at [2:3]

Comment: ok. so clearly in your question you are presenting data/structure that DOES NOT match to the data you actually use

Comment: Sry the schema inference read more number of rows than what my data sample had . updated the schema now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 

JSON_QUERY(message,"$.Key1") as Key1, 
JSON_QUERY(message,"$.Key2") as Key2

FROM 
`project.dataset.table`  as table 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(table.Messages) as message
```

CROSS JOIN for flattening the array,which will return a row for each message.

After that  “JSON_QUERY” to extract the needed values from the JSON string.